# Jquery Animate Divs, Animate One In Animate The Rest Out

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I try not to post many questions on StackExchange, unless I cant seem to find the solution. I'm still learning jQuery and have an issue with animating a left side menu sliding panel.

The aim of the sliding panel is to provide the user with information and links, pulled from a database. I'm trying to work out how to animate one panel in and animate (if there is already one currently opened) to animate out. So there can only be one panel open at any one time.

Here's my code so far:

```
$(".editor_content").hide();

//Panel 1
$('#tab_editor').toggle(function(){
    $('#panel_editor').animate({width:"400px", opacity:1.0}, 500, function() {
        $('.editor_content').fadeIn('slow');
        $('.wrapper').animate({"left": "190px"}, "slow");
    });  
},function(){ 
    $('.editor_content').fadeOut('fast', function() { 
        $('#panel_editor').stop().animate({width:"0", opacity:0.0}, 200);
        $('.wrapper').animate({"left": "0px"}, "slow");
    });
});

//Panel 2
$('#tab_themer').toggle(function(){
    $('#panel_themer').animate({width:"400px", opacity:1.0}, 500, function() {
        $('.themer_content').fadeIn('slow');
        $('.wrapper').animate({"left": "190px"}, "slow");
    });  
},function(){ 
    $('.themer_content').fadeOut('fast', function() { 
        $('#panel_themer').stop().animate({width:"0", opacity:0.0}, 200);
        $('.wrapper').animate({"left": "0px"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

The CSS for both Panels are set to `fixed top:0 left:0`.

With the above code the panels will animate in and out, but I cannot get my head around when one is clicked and animating in, how to animate the current one that is open out.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide a http://jsbin.com or a http://jsfiddle.net demo

Comment: Thanks for the Response Roko, I have created a rather CRUD example of what I have so far... http://jsfiddle.net/lee_marshall/SnYRC/ Let me know if you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should become aquainted with the javascript "this" variable.  This will allow you to write a function that will open the clicked on element and close the other elements.

Here is a fiddle I made for someone with a similar problem, they wanted to open a menu panel while closing any other open panels.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYUXP/3/)

Comment: Hi DaveR I can see what you have done with to allow for the various items to show and hide, im just wondering how this could be translated into animation rather than show/hide. Heres a Fiddle I created http://jsfiddle.net/lee_marshall/SnYRC/